# I'm trying to add from 1 to 10 using assembly and I have to use DI register

Tags: assembly, x86

I don't know is it okay to ask my report here.
In my system programming class, I'm using dos box emulator 0.74.

```
   MAIN SEGMENT
   ASSUME CS:MAIN, DS:MAIN
   MOV AX, CS
   MOV DS, AX
   TABLE DB 1
   DB 2
   DB 3
   DB 4
   DB 5
   DB 6
   DB 7
   DB 8
   DB 9
   DB 10
   LOOP1: MOV DI, 0;
   MOV AL, TABLE[DI];
   INC DI
   CMP DI, 9
   JBE LOOP1;
   MOV SUM, AL

   MOV AH, 4CH
   INT 21H

   SUM DB ?
  MAIN ENDS
   END
```

This is my code. And its assembling is fie. Link is fine. 
but exe doesn't respond. I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop.  You set DI back to zero in your loop, so it is always 0.  Move the instruction that initializes DI to before the `LOOP1` label.

Comment: Thank,you. I was an idiot. Thank you for escaping infinite loop. Thank you Thank you Thank you!!!